# File-Level Encryption

Tags: windows, encryption

I am looking for a **file-level** encryption program that ideally runs in the **right-click** context. Previously I utilized [AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/), however this has gone to a premium subscription-model, requiring a **$30.00** per year license to use AES-256!

Essentially I want file-level encryption (AES-256 as the preferred), that allows me to decrypt the **file** when used, and then encrypt when done.  The reason I want this is the data will be encapsulated in a PGP disk with encryption, thus adding another layer of support. Therefore, tools like EncFS and Veracrypt (to my knowledge) fail - they are encryption disks/partitions that store non-file level encrypted files within them.

Presently, I am trialing [AES Crypt](https://www.aescrypt.com/), however already have the following issues:

1. It makes a **duplicate** encrypted file, meaning I must delete the old file once performed.
2. When decrypting the file, if the name exists (as in `notes.txt`) it will not replace that file.
3. Concerns with automation of the process as listed [here](https://www.aescrypt.com/wishlist.html).

I have also trialed [crococryptFile](http://www.frankhissen.de/crococryptfile-home-en-frank-hissen-it-software.html) and have noted the following issues:

1. Each time a file is decrypted it is placed inside a `EncryptedFile` folder;
2. Multiple files/folders are not supported to be encrypted at any one time and;
3. The GUI feels bloaty/slow, and is not a "fast" process to perform actions.

---

**Requirements**

1. Support AES-256
2. Be less than $30.00(Australian Dollar) for single purchase
3. Run on Windows 10 natively
4. Have the capability to encrypted multiple files at once

**Nice to have:**

1. Right click context menu
2. Command line options (for batch processing)
3. Replace files when encrypted (`*.txt` becomes `*.encryption-file-type`)

Comment: AFAIK e.g. VeraCrypt can also use containers (not just disks and partitions). So that would mean "several files at once" – namely all that are inside that container. Not sure if there's "right-click support" (i.e. right click the container file to open/close), though, as a) I'm not using VeraCrypt and b) not using Windows.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, to clarify: I do not want *container* encryption, I want **file level** encryption inside an already encrypted container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Kruptos2](http://www.kruptos2.co.uk/)**

Kruptos2 coins the following as their product [descriptor](http://www.kruptos2.co.uk/kruptos2.html):

> Kruptos 2 Professional is an easy to use file encryption program that
>   uses 256-bit encryption to password protect your private files and
>   prevent them from being modified, read or even accessed without the
>   correct password. With Kruptos 2 you can password protect all your
>   sensitive personal and commercial information including your photos,
>   movies, credit card data, tax returns or any other private document.

Some key features of the product are inclusive of:

1. 256 bit Encryption
2. File Shredder
3. File name encryption
4. Password analyser

There are also other tools to help satisfy your requirements.

The total price for you is **$45.27** for their solution and their "USB to Go" product.

Comment: I had a quick look and this tool seems more of a suite product. I.E Using their GUI to open and close files, more than just the right click context menu. The product itself seems worthy, just not *what I want*. I'll upvote as a worthy applicant though.

Comment: I have edited your answer to be more informative. Once it has been peer reviewed and accepted, I will upvote it. Please keep in mind the more *relevant* information you post, the better the answer.

Comment: @DankyNanky,Kruptos 2 have all these nice to have features as well in addition to your requirements,    Right click context menu - Windows context menu integration - one click encryption
Command line options (for batch processing) - Kruptos 2 Pro supports
Replace files when encrypted (*.txt becomes *.encryption-file-type) - Encrypted will renamed to .k2p. In additon, if you want you can encrypt file names too.